# How do I add an "image guide" front of an UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to put an image (a guide so people can frame the picture correctly) in front of the camera preview of the UIImagePickerController.
How would I do that ?
thanks
Louis

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site, it should explain it: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/archives/821